# Could not locate a Bowtie index corresponding to basename

Tags: linux, alignment, bioinformatics

I am new to Bowtie. I am trying to use Bowtie for end to end local alignment. I've got this error message:

```
Could not locate a Bowtie index corresponding to basename "/bowtie2-index/hg19"
```

In my installation and in the bowtie2-index/hg19 folder there are six bt2 files. I am using the following command:

```
/opt/bowtie2/bowtie2-align-s --wrapper basic-0 -p 64 -x /mnt/miczfs/tide/bowtie2-index/hg19 -S /mnt/miczfs/tide/Data/chr2chr3/chr2chr3.sam -1 /mnt/miczfs/tide/Data/chr2chr3/chr2chr3.f1.fastq -2 /mnt/miczfs/tide/Data/chr2chr3/chr2chr3.f2.fastq
```

Comment: Have you checked out the manual? http://bowtie-bio.sourceforge.net/bowtie2/manual.shtml#getting-started-with-bowtie-2-lambda-phage-example

Comment: yes... but I can not find any useful thing about adding hg19 folder.

Answer (score 9):

This is a perennial question, I guess the documentation isn't explicit enough here. By using `-x /mnt/miczfs/tide/bowtie2-index/hg19`, you're telling bowtie2 that you have files like `/mnt/miczfs/tide/bowtie2-index/hg19.1.bt2` that it should use. You don't specify a folder, you specify a "basename". You probably meant `-x /mnt/miczfs/tide/bowtie2-index/hg19/hg19` or something like that.